# Does Boruto have Sasuke's headband?

Tags: naruto, boruto

In *Boruto*, does Boruto have Sasuke's headband (from the original *Naruto* series)? If so, why does Boruto have Sasuke's headband? Or will Boruto abandon Konoha sometime in the future, and put a missing-nin slash on his headband?

[image: Boruto with slashed headband]

This question was inspired by the above image. Also, what does the extra scar (which matches with Boruto's eye scar) mean? If that is Sasuke's headband, why would Boruto wear it instead of his own? Also wasn't Sasuke's headband blue, not black?

I would appreciate any canon references that explain this.

Comment: I highly doubt that the headband is of Sasuke but still according to me it is possible that Boruto have been given a secret mission which requires involvement with some bad people. But the cut in headband symbolizes that he has given up from village due to some reason. At the end you might need to wait for this answer.

Comment: Nothing's been revealed about the scar or backstory behind the scarred band. Time will tell..

Comment: Most recent episode of Boruto showed Sasuke giving him the headband so it is in fact Sasukes old headband.

Comment: @Milton but that headband is blue, the one above is black

Comment: @JohnD That's actually Sasuke's as the ninja of the current generation wear simple headbands, not being to be tied, unlike the old generation. It only seems black because it's dark and colors are slightly changed from manga to anime (e.g. In manga Sasuke's hair is pitch black, in anime, it's like a dark gray). Also may be an animation error of some sort as he's had that headband even after Isshiki died.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Boruto movie (which was released way before the Boruto manga/anime), after Boruto cheats on the chuunin examination, Naruto disqualifies him and takes his bandana from him. Later on, after Naruto is abducted, when Boruto shows determination to rescue his father, Sasuke is shown to give him "something", the scene cuts without showing what it is but in the next scene, just before they go through the portal Sasuke made, Boruto puts on a "scarred" bandana so it's implied it IS Sasuke's rogue ninja bandana. Later on he's shown with a normal bandana though, no clue whatsoever wether it was returned or not.

The bandana shown in that pic is one that you have to tie in the back, while the bandanas shown in the current series are mostly elastic ones (including Boruto's), which prompts me to believe that it's not Boruto's own bandana but an older ninja's, it very well may be Sasuke's given Boruto's attachment and admiration for him.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is his own headband because the extra scar matches with his eye.

Comment: It's highly probable that it is Sasuke's headband which he was wearing when he got the scar

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed Sasuke's headband. During the Chunin Exams arc, Boruto cheats using the Scientific Ninja Tool, and when Naruto figures out he says he is disqualified as a ninja and takes his headband. Later when the Five Kage, Sasuke, and Boruto are preparing to rescue Naruto, he gives Boruto his headband.

You may have noticed there is an extra slash other than the one Sasuke had. It is shown that the skin over Boruto's eye is slashed and some damage goes to his headband as well. That's why the slash and eye scar line up.

It is Sasuke's headband, but there is an extra slash because Boruto's eye is later scarred.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel like it's Naruto's. In *Shippuden*, Sasuke's headband cloth was never that long, but Naruto's was.

I'm not completely caught up so I could be wrong but so far that's my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The headband Boruto puts on is actually blue. Compared to his black jacket and his blue cloak, the cloak matches the headband so its most likely Sasuke's headband and not Naruto's.